# Manga- about the FL turned into a stone then the ML found her inside the dead dragon and hid her statue

Tags: story-identification, manga, magic, isekai

This is about the FL who can use magic then they have this kid in the basement (maybe the ML) who is like very strong yet trust no one. Then the FL became his guardian where he opens up with the FL. One day, they where given a mission but unexpectedly they met a dragon and saw one of there comrades badly hurt. The FL asked the comrade to run with the ML as she fought the dragon.

The FL put magic to the dragon as it was very old but in exchange turns her into statue. 20 years later she woked up with nice clothes and jewelry who looks like a goddess with the same age as she was 20 years ago and she was in this huge castle that's why she runs away. Then she was in this village where the soldier suddenly was looking fir the statue and they kept the village closed and that makes the villagers worry since they where looming for the goddess statue. But reality hits her as she think maybe she was the goddess, that's why she surrender herself to the guards and when they where back to the castle she saw the owner and it was the kid 20 years ago who she was guarding.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you recall the names of any of the characters?

Comment: Sadly, I don't remember any names I just read the manga online.

Comment: Just Found it! If you are all curious the title is: The Yandere Magician Can Only Love The Statue Maiden

Comment: @NAYAIL - Post that as a self-answer, please :-)